# JSON response with objects of the same name - Instagram comments

Tags: php, json, instagram

I have been building a test app that gathers pictures and certain pieces of user information from Instagram (only using PHP). I am not using the official API, but instead parsing the JSON response that I get from the url.

I'm trying to gather **comments** for a certain post. The issue is that when there's more than one comment, I can see the text for each comment, but the object name in the response is the same (it repeats for every comment): **{text}**.

Here's an abbreviated example response:

```
{"text":"I think this is funded by my company","created_at"...,"user":{"username"...}, blah blah blah},

{"text":"Very cool","created_at"...,"user":{"username"...blah blah blah
```

As you can see, for each comment made, there is a "text" object that I need to grab.

Here is my function (shortened) that parses the JSON and gets the comment text:

```
function scrape_insta_user_post($postid) {

  $insta_source = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/p/'.$postid.'/');
  $shards = explode('window._sharedData = ', $insta_source);
  $insta_json = explode(';</script>', $shards[1]); 
  $insta_array = json_decode($insta_json[0], TRUE);

  global $the_pic_comments;

  $the_pic_comments = $insta_array['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['media']['comments']['nodes'][0]['text'];

}
```

I have another function that I use to display $the_pic_comments by simply echoing the results.

```
echo $the_pic_comments;
```

In cases where there is more than one {text} object, how would I go about displaying each comment? I'm assuming some kind of foreach() loop might work, but I can't get the foreach() to work with my json_decode() function.

This currently works, but only displays one comment, and everything else is ignored.

Can you help me create a loop that will get each comment from the JSON response?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your code alone, it seems that it should be:

```
foreach ($insta_array['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['media']['comments']['nodes'] as $comment) {
    echo $comment['text']; // Or add to array, eg. $comments[] = $comment['text'];
}
```

Note that since you are not using official API, your mechanism may break any time without notice shall Instagram change anything in their code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried many variations of this and it's simply not printing out anything. I'm not sure why I can't get this to work. I'll keep playing around with it.

Comment: do var_dump($insta_array); and find where the actual array of comments is. it's pretty simple really!

Comment: Extremely simple, as you said. I was not running the loop in the correct place. Got it working with your help. Thanks again!